# How to get better precision on nth roots than std::pow?

Tags: c++, math, precision

I've got to perform some mathematical operations which involve the 12th root of 2. The following two lines output the value `1.05946` to the console.

```
double x = pow (2.0, 1.0/12.0);
cout << x << endl;
```

I was expecting more significant figures. Is there a better way of getting a precise value (accurate to ~9 sf) for nth roots?

Comment: Someone will be along soon to explain about setprecision...

Comment: Ah, got it. Cheers.

Comment: You can get even more digits by computing `expm1(log(2)/12)` which will give you the `x` in `1+x=2^(1/12)` with 16 significant digits.